# Excel MS 365 "save as" not show icon recent files in destination folder options

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to be able to choose "recent documents" when I save as a file excel...
When I "save as" an excel file in quick links it appears only a list of FREQUENT DESTINATION and RECENT files...

[image]

I need also RECENT FOLDERS!

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a built in capability to do this. Just go to `shell:recent` or `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` to get recently accessed files/folders.